# Angular select not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

controller

```
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.formData.cars = {};
$scope.formData.cars.list = [
    { id: 1, name: 'vw 2'},
    { id: 2, name: 'vw 1'}
];
$scope.formData.cars.selected = $scope.formData.cars.list[0];
```

html

```
<select id="bookingCars" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.cars.selected" ng-options="car.code as car.name for car in formData.cars.list">
```

Can anyone explain why this adds a 3rd blank element and why the first property (`vw 2`) isn't the default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ng-options="car as car.name for car in formData.cars.list"
```

and it should work: [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3fLeAKd2GsA6Da61DVKA?p=preview).

You are using `ngOption` in form `select as label for value in array`. [Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) says:

> select: The result of this expression will be bound to the model of
>   the parent  element. If not specified, select expression will
>   default to value.

So it means that you want your `select` part to be an object, however you provided a string `car.code`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use an Object to set the selected value because you are using the value "id" of your car.

So do something like this:

```
 $scope.formData = {};
 $scope.formData.cars = {};
 $scope.formData.cars.list = [
                        { id: 1, name: 'vw 2'},
                        { id: 2, name: 'vw 1'}
                    ];
$scope.formData.cars.selected = $scope.formData.cars.list[1].id;

<select id="bookingCars" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.cars.selected" ng-options="car.id as car.name for car in formData.cars.list">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KLDEZ/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the entire object as the value the following will work:

```
 {{formData.cars.selected}} -      {{formData.cars.selected.id}}
 <select id="bookingCars" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.cars.selected" 
 ng-options="c.name for c in formData.cars.list">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QZtEKWeXeHC9kcuEeGNi?p=preview